# autoreleased with no pool warning?

Tags: objective-c

I have audio class that sample the buffer and with `NSNotification` it calls another class and send a data(int).

I get this warning that runs many many times a second:

```
class __NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool()

class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

what does it means?
yes I have `NSNumber` in that class and `NSString`.
they are not allocated.

do I need another thread?
what's wrong?

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on `objc_autoreleaseNoPool()`? What does the stack show?

Comment: how do you put a breakpoint on objc_autoreleaseNoPool()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that, for whatever thread that code is running on, no [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsautoreleasepool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has been set up before that code runs. For AppKit- or UIKit-based apps, the framework normally managed one for you on the main thread, but you'll still need to create them yourself if you're using other threads. For apps that are not based on AppKit or UIKit, you'll pretty much always need to make sure there's an autorelease pool around when you're running Objective-C code.

Comment: What if you are using ARC and this is still happening? I am having this problem but Xcode won't let me add an NSAutoreleasePool.

Comment: @Justin: The `@autoreleasepool` directive ought to work. Does it not?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use an autorelease pool in your main() function in the application? Do you use the autoreleased instances (yes, I know, you didn't alloc-init them, but [NSNumber numberWith...] returns an alloc-init-autoreleased object) in a thread other than the main thread? If you haven't initially set up an autorelease pool, or you're using multiple threads, you must create an individual NSAutoreleasePool for each thread.

Comment: There are any number of reasons an object could be autoreleased besides being created that way — for instance, many accessor implementations will autoreleased objects. The safest version of a getter (I think it's used by synthesized accessors) works out to `return [[ivar retain] autorelease]`. It's just generally not safe to run arbitrary Foundation-based code without an autorelease pool in place.

Comment: Yes. But I wouldn't say the safest getter returns retain-autorelease. If an object does not exist, one should not expect its properties to exist, so it's kind of "abuse" or "overuse" of safety.

Comment: It's an Apple-sanctioned practice, so I would hardly call it "abuse." At any rate, it is quite common, so I wouldn't want to write code that misbehaves when it encounters this idiom.

Comment: Anyways, you're not supposed to access a deallocated object's property, are you?